# "Gave up waiting for root file system; Alert! UUID= ... does not exist! Dropping to a shell." Previous Thread Solutions have not Worked

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem, vmware, bootloader

I am running on VMware Workstation with Ubuntu 18.04.5. Whenever I try to boot my own Linux 5.4.0 Kernel, which so far is just fork of the original repo, I get this [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Bi9.png).

Here are some images that may be relevant:

[/etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgpT9.png),

[/etc/default/grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu4Oo.png),

[blkid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvKfx.png),

[ls /boot/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WubKJ.png)

Additionally, I have tried various fixes:

1. I set rootdelay=600; I have also tried using rootwait to no avail.
2. I have run `update-initramfs -u -k 5.4.0+`
3. I have run `mkconfig-grub; update-grub; update-grub2`
4. I have completely reinstalled my VM ova.
5. I have made sure that I am not using RAID; I am using AHCI.
6. Additionally when setting up the .config file I used the default recommended settings for 5.4.0.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to mount a floppy disk in /etc/fstab? What is all of that extra stuff in /etc/default/grub?

Comment: At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda1`.

Comment: Hello @heynnema, a lot of the extra stuff is related to the class I am taking for OS, I have in the past successfully used this ova with all of the extras.
I ran `fsck -f /dev/sda` and got:
"fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1"

Comment: You didn't do the `fsck` command correctly.

Comment: Ah, that's a typo. I did type `fsck -f /dev/sda1` I received the output
"fsck from util-linux 2.31.1 fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda1"

Comment: How is your disk physically connected? How do you run VMWare if you can't boot to your own disk?

Comment: Currently, VMware is using 50Gb off of one of my HDDs. I run VMware on a Windows 10 Computer and the screenshots of /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub are from a working kernel. If there is anymore specific information you need, I'd be more than happy to add in screenshots; I'm just not entirely sure what exactly would be relevant.

Comment: Did this ever work for you? Did you create this with *"fork of the original repo"*? I'm not exactly familiar with VMWare...

Comment: The kernel that is booting correctly came with the ova file for the virtual machine I am running. It is running the same version of Linux. In the past, I have used the repo that I forked from to create a working/bootable version of Linux that would run on this virtual machine.

Comment: I guess that I'm now over my head. Sorry.

Comment: Previous thread solutions are based on using the kernels that are released from Canonical.  Have you tried the official kernel that came with 18.04 to eliminate your kernel as being the problem?

Comment: It is likely that there is something wrong with my kernel that is stopping it from booting; however, the only thing that I have done with it is run (w/ sudo): `make oldconfig; make -j8; make modules_install; make install`. The version that is booting is the official kernel that came with 18.04, or at least I think it should be based on what I've read on ubuntu's website. Typing `cat /proc/version_signature` I get: `Ubuntu 5.4.0-80.90~18.04.1-generic 5.4.124`